# how can I make a single join value match a range of values

Tags: sql, inner-join

In my software system, an important lookup column historically had one of three numeric values.

We're now going to allow more values in between, but I still need to be able to map all in-between values on the original three-point scale.

The system is for rating positive, neutral, and negative based on an integer value. it use to be 2, 4, and 6

We have now gone to a -5 to +5 rating system, but still only use 2, 4, and 6 to pass in positive neutral and negative values.

In the database we had a sproc written that returned rows with exactly 2 or 4 or 6, but now it needs to return rows with
-5 through -2 if it's 6. 
-1 through 1 if 4. 
and -2 through -5 if 2.

This is how the inner Join was written

```
INNER JOIN @SiteIDs sti ON sti.SiteID = s.SiteID
        --AND d.SiteID IN (ISNULL(@SiteIDList, d.SiteID))
        AND ISNULL(s.DatePosted, '1/1/1901') >= ISNULL(@StartDate, '1/1/1900')
        AND ISNULL(s.DatePosted, '1/1/9998') <= ISNULL(@EndDate, '1/1/9999')
        AND s.Favorite = CASE WHEN @FavoritesOnly = 1 THEN 1 ELSE s.Favorite END
        AND s.SID = ISNULL(@SID, s.SID) -- this is what needs to be changed
```

I know what needs to happen:
when @SID is 6 s.sid needs to return all values that are -2, -3, -4 and -5, and similarly for the other two ranges. 
I'm just not sure how to syntax it properly.

Comment: This is the join -- where is the part that returned the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
INNER JOIN @SiteIDs sti ON sti.SiteID = s.SiteID
    --AND d.SiteID IN (ISNULL(@SiteIDList, d.SiteID))
    AND ISNULL(s.DatePosted, '1/1/1901') >= ISNULL(@StartDate, '1/1/1900')
    AND ISNULL(s.DatePosted, '1/1/9998') <= ISNULL(@EndDate, '1/1/9999')
    AND s.Favorite = CASE WHEN @FavoritesOnly = 1 THEN 1 ELSE s.Favorite END
    AND s.SID between 
        case coalesce(@SID,0) 
            when 6 then -5
            when 4 then -1
            when 2 then 2
            default s.SID --if @SID is not valid, all results are returned 
        end
        and  
        case coalesce(@SID,0) 
            when 6 then -2
            when 4 then 1
            when 2 then 5
            default s.SID
        end
```

Comment: sure is thanks for the help it put me on the right track for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
AND @SID is null or @SID = 6 and SID in (-2, -3, -4, -5)
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you had something like this:

```
SELECT rating -- this used to return 2, 4, or 6
...
```

now needs to be

```
SELECT CASE WHEN rating = 6 THEN -1
            WHEN rating = 4 THEN -2
            WHEN rating = 2 THEN -5
            ELSE 0 -- this is an error
       END AS rating
...
```

IF you want to do this only when @SID = 6 then

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @SID = 6 AND rating = 6 THEN -1
            WHEN @SID = 6 AND rating = 4 THEN -2
            WHEN @SID = 6 AND rating = 2 THEN -5
            ELSE rating
       END AS rating
...
```